# CSS not working in PaxWeb Http Whiteboard

Tags: pax-web

I am using PaxWeb Http Whiteboard service in Apache Karaf; while everything works, I am unable to get certain CSS styles rendered properly - 
for example,

```
arrow-dropup-circle {
    content: "\f364";
}
```

This is supposed to display a drop up circle but when hosted in PaxWeb, though the css is loaded; it does not render the content. While it displays square boxes in chrome, in firefox; it just shows the number f364 in a square box.

Please note that this works when I host my website in NodeJS.

My blueprint is same as the one given here.

Can someone shed some light into why am not getting css rendered properly?

Thanks
Venkatesh Laguduva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same issue. In my case, font files (like .ttf, .woff) were failed to decode while loading the page. Maven was corrupting that. It is filtering files with those extensions. To exclude files from filtering based on the extension, we can use "nonFilteredFileExtensions" tag in pom.  This solved my decoding issue.